# liferay spring portal @ResourceMapping can't trigger different types of http methods

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, liferay-6, thymeleaf

I have created a liferay portlet application using **Spring**, **thymeleaf** and **AngularJS**. For communication between `AngularJS` and spring I need to create some rest calls which I have created using `@ResourceMapping` like as shown below. The application is working fine but the problem is that I don't know how to make `GET`, `DELETE`, `PUT` http `REST` calls since `@ResourceMapping` is not allowing to specify any methods.

```
@ResourceMapping(value="getUserDetail")
public void userDetail(@RequestParam long userId, ResourceResponse response) throws Exception {
    Users users = new Users(userId);
    // some logic 

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    JSON_MAPPER.writeValue(response.getPortletOutputStream(), users);
}
```

When I used `@RequestMapping` instead of `@ResourceMapping` like as shown below

```
@RequestMapping(value="getUserDetail", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void userDetail(@RequestParam long userId, ResourceResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Got detail request for user with id {} "+ userId);

    // UserDetail userDetail = this.userService.getPortalUserDetail(userId);
    List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
    users.add("Manu");
    users.add("Lissie");
    users.add("John");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    JSON_MAPPER.writeValue(response.getPortletOutputStream(), users);
}
```

I have got

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mode mappings conflict between method and type level: [getUserDetail] versus [view]
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

1. How to create different types of http calls using `@ResourceMapping`
2. Can we use `@RequestMapping` instead of `@ResourceMapping` in Liferay Spring portlet for `REST` calls
3. How can we create resource based `REST` urls like `getUser/12/mumbai`
4. How can we send `REST` json as body instead of Request Param

Comment: Well did you solve your problem? And if yes what did you do?

Comment: @ChristosBaziotis When I tried with@RequestMapping I got `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping'‌​: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mode mappings conflict between method and type level: [getUserDetail] versus [view]`

Comment: @ChristosBaziotis do I need to use any extra configuration for using `@RequestMapping`

Comment: @ChristosBaziotis As Tomáš Piňos said I have created a separate controller class and annotataed as `@Controller` and have created a `@RequestMapping` function like as above, now I am getting 404

Comment: Please tell me the 1) whole URL you used before and 2) the `@RequestMapping` value that you use now. The `@RequestMapping` must have placed the endpoint in a different URL. For example if before you used `localhost:12345/api/getSomething`, maybe now the endpoint is under `localhost:12345/getSomething` or the opposite.

Comment: @ChristosBaziotis The URL i have used to access before when I used @ResourceMapping is `http://localhost:8082/web/guest/welcome?p_p_id=fileprocessorportlet_WAR_fil%E2%80%A6e=view&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=3&p_p_resource_id=userDetail&userId=1`. Now I have My controller class as [SampleRESTFullController.java](https://gist.github.com/nidhishkrishnan/cc71de6b7dc7c0cebc46) and I have tries to call it as `http://localhost:8082/file-processor-portlet/services/auth/user`but got 404

Comment: Check under `http://localhost:8082/auth/user` or `http://localhost:8082/file-processor-portlet/auth/user` or `http://localhost:8082/services/auth/user`. I don't know how you have configured your app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93358/discussion-between-alex-man-and-christos-baziotis).

Answer (score 3):

**Mode mappings conflict** exception

The question doesn't show it, but your controller probably has `@RequestMapping("view")` annotation. This type level mapping is in conflict with the method level mappings. You should remove `@RequestMapping` annotation on the controller class.

**Request mapping examples**

```
@Controller
public class SampleRESTFullController {

// Simple GET
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloSample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody List<HelloSample> helloSample() { ... }

// GET with path variable
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloSample/sampleId/{sampleId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody HelloSample helloSample(@PathVariable("sampleId") Long sampleId) { ... }

// POST with @RequestBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloSample", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public @ResponseBody HelloSample createSample(@RequestBody HelloSample helloSample) { ... }

// PUT with path variable and @RequestBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloSample/sampleId/{sampleId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
void update(@PathVariable("sampleId") long sampleId, @RequestBody HelloSample helloSample) { ... }

// DELETE
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloSample/sampleId/{sampleId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
void delete(@PathVariable("sampleId") long sampleId) { ... }

}
```

I took the examples from [Using RESTFul services with Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/web/vitor.silva/blog/-/blogs/using-restful-services-with-liferay) blog post. It answers all your questions and presents tons of examples. Pay attention to Spring configuration, which makes the RESTful services possible (especially the view resolver and message converter).

Comment: @TomasPinos I have created a separate controller class and annotataed as `@Controller` and have created a `@RequestMapping` function like as above, now I am getting 404

Comment: Can you come for a chat at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93360/discussion-on-liferay-spring-portal-resourcemapping-cant-trigger-different-type

Answer (score 2):

```
1. How to create different types of http calls using @ResourceMapping
```

If you want to a REST Api with Complete Actions (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) you need to use `@RequestMapping`.

```
2. Can we use @RequestMapping instead of @ResourceMapping in Liferay Spring portlet for REST calls
```

You should be able to use.

```
3. How can we create resource based REST urls like getUser/12/mumbai

@RequestMapping(value="getUser/{userId}/mumbai", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<String> userDetail(@RequestParam("userId") long userId) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Got detail request for user with id {} "+ userId);

    //UserDetail userDetail = this.userService.getPortalUserDetail(userId);
    List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
    users.add("Manu");
    users.add("Lissie");
    users.add("John");

    return users;
}

4. How can we send REST json as body instead of Request Param

    You can use @RequestBody

    @RequestMapping(value="saveUser/{userId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void userDetail(@RequestParam("userId") long userId, @RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
        // Logic
    }
```

Comment: When I tried with@RequestMapping I got `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mode mappings conflict between method and type level: [getUserDetail] versus [view]`

Comment: Are you having any duplicate mappings? Please show your full code.

Comment: @shakin can you tell me your email address

Comment: @shakin any idea on this, hope you have seen my code

Answer (score 2):

### How to create different types of http calls using @ResourceMapping

Here are some examples that may help you, that's how i use `@RequestMapping`:

```
// GET
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/something", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public boolean getSomething() {
    return "something";
}

// GET with param
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/something/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public boolean getSomething(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return id;
}
```

Instead of `RequestMethod.GET` you can use `RequestMethod.POST`,`RequestMethod.PUT`,`RequestMethod.DELETE` and so on...

### How can we send REST json as body instead of Request Param

Here is a code snippet that i currently use with an AngularJS FrontEnd for user registration. It works just fine and i use @RequestMapping:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody User user) {
        user = userService.initUser(user);
        Authentication authentication = securityUserDetailsService.register(user);
        if (authentication != null) {
            SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            context.setAuthentication(authentication);
            User authUser = securityUserDetailsService.getAuthenticatedUser();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(authUser, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

In order to [consume JSON](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--) you do:

```
RequestMapping(value = "/whatever", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

In order to [produce (return) JSON](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--) you do:

```
RequestMapping(value = "/whatever", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Also since you use Spring i think you should take a look at [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) and [Spring Data Rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/). This way you can expose your business models as RESTful endpoints.

### How can we create resource based REST urls like getUser/12/mumbai

So in order to expose this endpoint `getUser/12/mumbai` that's what you should do:

```
// mumbai hardcoded
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUser/{id}/mumbai", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    // go get the user ...
    return user;
}

// mumbai as a param
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUser/{id}/{prop}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @PathVariable("prop") String prop) {
    // go get the user ...
    return user;
}
```

---

Lastly can you please try to change

```
public void userDetail (...
```

to this

```
public ResponseEntity<userDetail > (...
```

Answer (score 2):

> There are following methods to use rest app with angular js

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveuser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@RequestMapping(value = "/getemployee", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@RequestMapping(value = "/editCountry", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteCountry", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
```

> and use following javascript to communicate with spring controller

```js
var formData = {
    "userName" : 'Vasim',
    "password" : '123456',
    "roleName" : 'Admin'
   };
   var response = $http.post('add', formData);
   response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.message = data;
   });
var formData = {
    "userName" : 'Vasim',
    "password" : '123456',
    "roleName" : 'Admin'
   };
   var response = $http.put('edit', formData);
   response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.message = data;
   });
$scope.delete= function(employeeId) {
   $http['delete']('delete', {
    params : {
     'employeeId' : employeeId
    }
   }).

   success(function(data) {

    $scope.msg = data;
 
   });
 $http.get('get',{params:{
 'id':id
 }
                 }).success(function(data) {

   $scope.employees = data;
```

Comment: but @RequestMapping is not woprking

Comment: iamvasim786@gmail.com